# Валидация ссылки профилей из соц сетей js regex

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Хочу сделать правильную валидацию полей, для ввода линков, профайлов, из соц сетей.

Валидация проходит с помощью паттерна, и обрабатывается js внутри кода таким образом :

```
pattern = [а-яА-Яa-zA-Z]+
```

То хотел бы правильно сделать подобный паттерн, для трех полей (трех соц сетей) с приведенными ниже ссылками.

Это делаеться для того что бы пользователь вводил верный урл профайла своей соц сети, я замечал данный функционал на некоторых форумных профайлах (там работает не много по другому, вводиш ссылку, а он автоматом из нее парсит ник нейм, или айди) а на форуме просто подставляет урл.

Можно и такой вариант. Думаю он для реализации будет легче.

**Вот список форматов профайлов**

Хотел бы узнать как лучше всего организовать данную валидацию, с регулярками не очень знаком, но и гороздить тонну кода, тоже не хочется, может есть оптимальный вариант.

**Вконтакте:**

```
http://vk.com/id2123445566 
http://vk.com/nick_name
http://vk.com/nickname
```

**Фейсбук:**

```
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=12312312123123
https://www.facebook.com/nickname
```

**Одноклассники:**

```
https://ok.ru/nickname
https://ok.ru/profile/123123231231
```

Comment: В чём вопрос? Что вы попытались сделать до того как спросить? И что именно вызвало трудности в собственном решении?

Comment: Вопрос в том, как лучше, проще это сделать

Comment: Как лучше сделать валидацию на JS с помощью регулярки? Написать регулярку, ловить событие ввода урла .. проверять соответствие данных в строке регулярке. Или вы более одного варианта решения видите?

Comment: Можно сказать так, я искал универсального простого решение. Допустим самый простой вариант, это, пилить регулярку, под два и более формата одного урл. Но есть ли решение проще ? Если нет, тогда вопрос в том, как правильно написать универсальную регулярку, что бы валидировала данные форматы с https, http и запрещала форматы не соответсвующие паттернам ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Регулярки для поиска идешки в урле профиля с идешкой:

```
// vk
(/https?:\/\/(www\.)?vk\.com\/id\d+/i).test('http://vk.COM/id2123445566');
// fb
(/https?:\/\/(www\.)?facebook\.com\/profile\.php\?id=\d+/i).test('https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=12312312123123');
// ok
(/https?:\/\/(www\.)?ok\.ru\/profile\/\d+/i).test('https://ok.ru/profile/123123231231');
```

Если в урле не идешка, а никнейм, то вам так или иначе придётся собрать все зарезервированные урлы, которые похожи на ссылки на профиль, но не являются ими. Например, `/feed` вконтакте - страница это новостей или профиль пользователя? Регуляркой этого не определить.

Comment: О, тут вы хорошо подметили, я как то об этом и не подумал. Просто не хочется что бы собирался мусор. Хотя в таком случае можно просто придумать чистильщика по курлу. Уже со своими наворотами. Вобщем логику понял. (Универсального решение нет) даже в том случае если юзер введет ВЕРНЫЙ но не свой профайл.. :)